# Translate SMAPE Calculation from Tableau to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Trying to get this calculation in Tableau to work in BI, but im stuck for a while now. In Tableau it's like:

`{INCLUDE  [Product Key]:  2*ABS(SUM([Constr Demand])-SUM([Actual Qty]))/SUM(ABS([Constr Demand])+ABS([Actual Qty]))}`

What I've tried is many different DAX sollutions but i'm not getting the correct value. If i split them up, i get the same vales in voth parts, but Tableau sums each row, then averages the value, and thats what messing it up for me.
My latest trial doesnt give much values back but the logic is sort of correct compared to tableau.

```
 #SMAPE Prod =
   AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        df_backtest_day,df_backtest_day[product_key],
        "Sum_2Times",
        2*ABS(
            SUM(df_backtest_day[constr_demand])-SUM(df_backtest_day[actual_qty])
        )
        /
        ABS(
            SUMX(df_backtest_day,df_backtest_day[constr_demand]+df_backtest_day[actual_qty]
            )
        )
    ),[Sum_2Times]
)
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data with your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found that adding `DIVIDE` in the part `SUMMARIZE` it did the trick.

```
#SMAPE Prod = 
AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        df_backtest_day,df_backtest_day[product_key],
        "Sum_2Times",
        DIVIDE(
        2*ABS(
            SUM(df_backtest_day[constr_demand])-SUM(df_backtest_day[actual_qty])
        )
        ,
        ABS(
            SUMX(df_backtest_day,df_backtest_day[constr_demand]+df_backtest_day[actual_qty]
            )
        )
    )),[Sum_2Times]
)
```